# Javascript de conexão com o banco não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, apache-cordova, mobile

Olá, estou tentando conectar ao banco de dados MySQL com um projeto Phonegap/Cordova e estou tento problemas. Primeiramente criei o projeto Cordova e a única alteração que fiz foi importar o JQuery. Daí segui um tutorial pra fazer uma chamada ajax de um arquivo php que deveria inserir os dados no banco, tudo à grosso modo mas mesmo assim não funciona. Alguém, por favor, me ajuda!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        
        
        
        
        Hello World

```
    <form id="formUsuario">
        <input id="nomeUsuario" type="text" placeholder="Nome"></input> <br>
        <input id="sobrenomeUsuario" type="text" placeholder="Sobrenome"></input> <br>
        <input id="idadeUsuario" type="text" placeholder="Idade"></input> <br>

        <button id="enviar" type="submit" onclick="salvar()">Enviar</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function salvar(){
            alert('Botão salvar clicado!');

            var formula = $('#formUsuario').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dados: formula,
                url: 'http://localhost/projetos/wstest/cadastrar.php',
                success: function(data){
                    if (data == 0) {
                        alert('Erro ao se comunicar com o banco de dados!');
                        window.location = "";
                    }
                    else if (data == 1) {
                        alert('Registro salvo com sucesso!');
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Algo de errado aconteceu!');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

    app.initialize();
```

**conexao.php**

```
    <?php

    //Conecta ao banco de dados usando MySQLi
    function conectar()
    {
        try
        {
            //Localhost
            $host = "localhost";
            $user = "root";
            $password = "";
            $database = "webservice";

            $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
//            mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE);
            echo 'Conexão bem sucedida!';

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die("Erro de conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        return $conn;
    }
```

**cadastrar.php**

```
<?php

include './conexao.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$link = conectar();

$nome       = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['nomeUsuario']);
$sobrenome  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['sobrenomeUsuario']);
$idade      = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['idadeUsuario']);

$query = "INSERT INTO `usuario`(`nome`, `sobrenome`, `idade`) "
        ."VALUES ('$nome','$sobrenome','$idade')";

$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if($res == true){
    $resultado = 1;
}else{
    $resultado = 0;
}

echo (json_encode($resultado));
```

Rodo isso no navegador usando o Ripple e não funciona. Nem o alert de erro eu recebo. Muito menos debugando no telefone. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço imensamente.

Comment: Em `mysqli_real_escape_string` precisa passar a conexão como primeiro argumento, se o problema é o php, teste ele isolado.

Comment: Note que você tem um erro no envio do js, `dados: 'formula',`, deve ser `data: formula,`

Comment: Já retifiquei essa parte, obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho Você ajustou com `dados` ou `data`? lembre que é inglês.

Answer (score 1):

No estilo procedural do MySQLi quase todas as funções pedem como primeiro argumento a conexão, [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) não é a exceção.

Mude e as demais linhas de:

```
$nome       = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['nomeUsuario']);
```

Para:

```
$nome       = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['nomeUsuario']);
```

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho vc consegue rodar essa página pelo navegador (desktop)? veja o console de erros do javascript lá deve ter alguma pista.

Comment: Estou recebendo o seguinte erro no console: GET http://localhost/projetos/cordova/testapp/www/cordova.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho se vc colocar a url relativa funciona? no lugar de `localhost/projetos ... / demais pastas` como `../php/arquivo.php`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45975/discussion-between-guilherme-ramalho-and-rray).

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava recebendo o seguinte erro no console:

> Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-vEvqxevWs9eHGtUlhoHXpL4h80s+E4s8/84jnjsED6E='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Ao que parece esse erro acontece devido à uma [Política de estruturação de código javascript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) que é definido pela seguinte tag html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Ao remover a tag o JQuery passou à funcionar.